# Multiple component file connect to redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

How I can connect file with multiple components to redux using connect() function?

I have connected other components in the bottom component in export. It is possible to connect.

I have connected other like this, but in file with multiple I can`t export like that.

```
const PageKierowcyTableView = (props) =>{
return (
    <JSX>
  )
};
export connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(PageKierowcyTableView )
```

```
export const PageKierowcyTableView = (props) =>{
return (
    <JSX>
  )
};


export const PageRozliczeniaNaMoimAucieTable = (props) => {
  return (
    <JSX>
  );
};

export const PageRozliczeniaNaSwoimAucieTable = (props) => {
    return (
      <JSX>
    );
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use named exports instead of the default export. E.g.

```
const PageKierowcyTableView = (props) => ...;

const PageRozliczeniaNaMoimAucieTable = (props) => ...;

const PageRozliczeniaNaSwoimAucieTable = (props) => ...;

export const ConnectedPageKierowcyTableView = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(PageKierowcyTableView)

export const ConnectedPageRozliczeniaNaMoimAucieTable = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(PageRozliczeniaNaMoimAucieTable)

export const ConnectedPageRozliczeniaNaSwoimAucieTable = connect(mapStateToProps,actions)(PageRozliczeniaNaSwoimAucieTable)
```

Depending on your components you might also have different `mapStateToProps` implementations.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I understand, but I looked for solution with the same component name. I don`t wanna repeat myself. I`ve already passed props down from parent component, but thanks for your solution.

Comment: If they all use the same mapStateToProps and actions then you can save that to a variable, like const withProps = connect( mapStateToProps, actions ).  Then use that same HOC on all components.  export const ConnectedPageKierowcyTableView = withProps(PageKierowcyTableView).  You could also define the inner component inline.  export const PageKierowcyTableView = withProps( props => … )

Comment: I don`t think about it. I will use it. Thanks :)